# Epics disappear from Scrum board

Tags: scrum, jira, epics

I have started a project, which should be done with Scrum. So, I am adding Epics to Backlog in Jira, and they disappear. How can I show Epics in Backlog? Thanks.

Comment: I have discovered like only tasks can be seen in Baklog.

Comment: You will find only user stories, tasks and bugs in the backlog. Epics will be visible in a separate section as mentioned by @Thomas Owens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jira, Epics are containers for smaller units of work, which are often represented by other issue types like Story, Bug, and Task. Epics won't appear in the Backlog view in Jira, however they will appear in the sidebar. There are two tabs - "Versions" and "Epics". From this panel, you can view a list of Epics, expand an Epic to view details (number of issues in the Epic, number of completed issues, number of estimated and unestimated issues, and a progress bar showing in progress and done work). By clicking on one of these Epics, you can filter the backlog view to only show items that are part of that Epic.

Comment: Thanks for adding problem solution!!!